# Using the Scala type system to flexibly assert that a base class has some combination of additional properties

Tags: scala, types

I have a scala class that looks like this:

```
class Zoo {
    val name: String 
    val location: String 

    val lion: Option[Object]
    val tiger: Option[Object]
    val bear: Option[Object]
}
```

Code that uses Zoo has to check at runtime whether lion, tiger and/or bear is present.  I'd like to make it possible to assert at compile-time which animals are present.

Currently I have something like the following:

```
class Zoo {
    val name: String
    val location: String
}

case class ZooWithBear(zoo: Zoo, bear: Bear)
case class ZooWithLion(zoo: Zoo, lion: Lion)
case class ZooWithTiger(zoo: Zoo, tiger: Tiger)

def foo(zooWithBear: ZooWithBear) : Int
```

Obviously this breaks down when I want to assert that a combination of animals must exist -- the number of case classes explodes.

I could also use traits like HasBear, HasLion and HasTiger.  That works great in method signatures (`def foo(z: Zoo with HasLion)`), but given an instance of Zoo with some unknown set of additional traits, there's no way to add a trait.  (Via some sort of `zoo.withTiger(tiger): Self with HasTiger` type method.)  I have to know all the present animals at initial construction of the zoo.

Given a base class with common properties like Zoo, how can I use the type system to flexibly create instances of Zoo with additional properties and make assertions in method signatures that incoming instances of Zoo have a particular set of additional properties?

Comment: Consider that relationship. A Zoo has animals. Zoo is a class, Animal is a class. The keyword 'with' should tell you there is a linking relationship and not a 'is' relationship involved. If that makes sense? Therefore, for this question, the appropriate action is the boolean hasAnimal(Animal animal) etc...
You can then have Animal be the parent of each of the animal classes.

Comment: @ErickStone I understand that I'm abusing the type system in a way that runs afoul of OO principles, but I'd still like to figure out if it's possible :-).  hasAnimal(Animal animal) sounds reasonable, except that would only work at runtime.  I'd like to be able to make assertions at compile time.  (e.g. `def someMethod(zoo: Zoo with HasBear with HasTiger)`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve what you want, you can use mixins and compose the types, and make a match with the combinations first and then with the particular cases, like this:

```
class Zoo(name: String = "Madagascar", location: String = "Africa")

trait HasBear
trait HasLion
trait HasTiger

val myZoo1 = new Zoo with HasBear with HasLion with HasTiger
val myZoo2 = new Zoo with HasBear with HasLion
val myZoo3 = new Zoo with HasBear with HasTiger
val myZoo4 = new Zoo with HasLion with HasTiger
val myZoo5 = new Zoo with HasBear
val myZoo6 = new Zoo with HasLion
val myZoo7 = new Zoo with HasTiger

def foo(zoo: Zoo) : Int = {
  zoo match {
    case _: Zoo with HasBear with HasLion with HasTiger => 1
    case _: Zoo with HasBear with HasLion => 2
    case _: Zoo with HasBear with HasTiger => 3
    case _: Zoo with HasLion with HasTiger => 4
    case _: HasBear  => 5
    case _: HasLion => 6
    case _: HasTiger => 7
  }
}

foo(myZoo1)
foo(myZoo2)
foo(myZoo3)
foo(myZoo4)
foo(myZoo5)
foo(myZoo6)
foo(myZoo7)
```

**Important: In the match, you must first add the case with more traits first and then with less, if you don't the match won't be as expected**

Comment: Awesome, I think this gets most of the way there.  How would I add a method to Zoo like:  `def withBear(bear: Bear) : Self with HasBear`?

Comment: @FullTimeCoderPartTimeSysAdmin where do you want that method? and what that method does?

Comment: I mean, the method foo, as I can tell, does exactly that, did you see my update? You give to it a zoo, and return something in base of the animals it has

Comment: Oh I see, I could use it to construct a zoo with the appropriate traits